# Need recommendation for a complex analysis book toward number theory

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, book-recommendation

Can someone suggest a good book for learning complex analysis before studying analytic number theory?
I have seen the books by Ahlfors, Rudin, Stein but they develop theory. Is there a book (preferably with exercises) where one can learn more about the types of bounds used in Number Theory that come from complex analysis? Like bounds on locations of zeros of analytic functions etc....

Thanks a lot

Comment: Freitag-Busam complex analysis https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540939825

Comment: seconding Freitag